# How to return two values or array from function in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, numerical-methods

I have a code on Fortran that solves equations eq1 and eq1 numerically using secant and bisection methods.

```
FUNCTION eq1(x) RESULT(y)
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: x, y
        y = x**4d0 + 18d0*x - 10d0
    END FUNCTION
    
    FUNCTION eq2(x) RESULT(y)
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: x, y
        y = 5d0**x - 6d0*x - 3d0
    END FUNCTION
    
    FUNCTION MC(f, eps, a, b)
        DOUBLE PRECISION, EXTERNAL :: f
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: eps, x1, x2, x3, a, b, i
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: MC(2)
        x1 = a
        x2 = b
        i = 0d0
        DO
            i = i + 1d0
            x3 = x2 - f(x2)*((x2 - x1)/(f(x2) - f(x1)))
            IF(dABS((x3 - x2)*(x2 - x1)) < eps) THEN
                EXIT
            END IF
            x1 = x2
            x2 = x3
        END DO
        MC(1) = i
        MC(2) = x3
    END FUNCTION MC
    
    FUNCTION MPD(f, eps, a1, b1) RESULT(c)
        DOUBLE PRECISION, EXTERNAL :: f
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: eps, a, b, c, a1, b1
        a = a1
        b = b1
        
        DO WHILE(dABS(b - a)/2d0 >= eps)
            c = (a+b)/2d0
            IF(f(a)*f(c) < 0d0) THEN
                b = c
            ELSE
                a = c
            END IF
        END DO
    END FUNCTION
    
    PROGRAM lab1
    IMPLICIT NONE
        DOUBLE PRECISION, EXTERNAL :: eq1, eq2, MC, MPD
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: eps
        DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(2,2) :: mat
    
        eps = 1e-6
    
        mat(1,1) = 0.3d0
        mat(1,2) = 0.6d0
        mat(2,1) = 1.0d0
        mat(2,2) = 1.6d0
        
        WRITE (*,*) MC(eq1, eps, mat(1,1), mat(1,2))
        WRITE (*,*) MPD(eq1, eps, mat(1,1), mat(1,2))
        WRITE (*,*) MC(eq2, eps, mat(2,1), mat(2,2))
        WRITE (*,*) MPD(eq2, eps, mat(2,1), mat(2,2))
    
        READ(*,*) 
    END PROGRAM lab1
```

I want the MC function to return an array consisting of the solution to the equation and the number of iterations.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error from MSVS:The rank of the function reference does not match the rank of the function definition.

How to fix it?